# Android Studio: Dependency issues

Tags: android, dependencies

```
compile 'com.github.RogaLabs:social-login:1.2.1'
compile 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:social-login-helper:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.robertsimoes:Shareable:0.1.0'
compile 'com.github.fccaikai:BottomMenuTutorial:1.0.1'
```

I tried some other libraries too, they were also giving such type of errors but when I used Glide or Picasso library they synced perfectly.

but getting following error

[image]

> I am using Gradle version: 2.14.1

Comment: missing there `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`??

Comment: Thanks IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first make sure you add **jitpack.io** in `build.gradle` ***Root level*** Section .

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

After that **Clean-Rebuild** and **Run** .